# How do I download a file over python socket with a tqdm status bar?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, tqdm

I have tried the to download a file over a **low-level python socket** but its taking too long to download. Example a file **70,000 kilobytes is taking 50 seconds**. 
I am using the **tqdm** python module as my progress bar though i have only managed to use it when **when writing to file**, that's when **all** or **some** bytes have been **received to write**.

server.py

```
import socket
import os
from tqdm import tqdm

s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("", 4444))
s.listen(1000)
print("listening...")

while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print("connection to the client established....")

    file_name = input("filename: ")
    conn.send(bytes(file_name, "utf-8"))

    file_size = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

    conn.send(b"start transfer...")

    file_data = conn.recv(int(file_size))

    for data in tqdm(range(int(file_size))):
        with open(file_name, "wb") as write_f:
            write_f.write(file_data)

    print("transfer complete...")
    conn.close()
    os._exit(1)
```

client.py

```
import socket
import os

s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("192.168.1.6", 4444))

file_name = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

file_size = s.send(bytes(os.stat(file_name).st_size, "utf-8"))

confirmation = s.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")

with open(file_name, "rb") as read_f:
    file_data = s.send(read_f.read())

s.close()
os._exit(1)
```